# PromiseKit compilation errors

Tags: swift, promisekit, xcode11.4

I'm new to `PromiseKit` however I can't get something very basic to work. Consider this:

```
func test1() -> Promise<Bool> {
    return Promise<Bool>.value(true)
  }

  func test2() -> Promise<Bool> {
    return Promise<Bool> { seal in
      seal.fulfill(true)
    }
  }

  func test3() -> Promise<Bool> {
    return Promise<Bool>.value(true)
  }
```

The following gives me the error on each line:

> Cannot convert value of type `Promise<Bool>` to closure result type
>   `Guarantee<()>`

```
 firstly {
    test1()
  }.then {
    test2()
  }.then {
    test3()
  }.done {

  }.catch {

  }
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been trying various combinations but nothing seems to work. I'm on `PromiseKit 6.13`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `PromiseKit` troubleshooting [guide](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/Troubleshooting.md):

> Swift does not permit you to silently ignore a closure's parameters.

So you have to just [specify](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/Troubleshooting.md#acknowledge-all-incoming-closure-parameters) closure parameter like below:

```swift
firstly {
        test1()
    }.then { boolValue in
        self.test2()
    }.then { boolValue in
        self.test3()
    }.done { _ in

    }.catch { _ in

    }
```

or even with assigning the `_` name to the parameter (acknowledge argument existence but ignoring its name)

```swift
firstly {
        test1()
    }.then { _ in
        self.test2()
    }.then { _ in
        self.test3()
    }.done { _ in

    }.catch { _ in

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I eventually figured it out after going over the documentation, and I can see what they meant when they say the Swift compiler may throw bogus errors at you. Aargh. Frustrating how it didn't show a more meaningful compiler error. Cannot believe I ended up wasting so much time on something so obvious.